# Why python-magic returns wrong mime-type if file size is too small?

Tags: python, mime-types, python-magic

In case of the file size is under 5000 bytes (InMemoryUploadedFile).
This code doesn't work

```
mime_type = magic.from_buffer(file.read(), mime=True)
```

It returns wrong mime_type.
For example, I have a file cv.docx with 4074 bytes size.
It returns a mime_type:

```
'application/x-empty'
```

instead of

```
'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
```

Could you please suggest me any advices to solve this case?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @ruohola No, I couldn't solve this, I tried to use this: file.seek(0) mime_type = magic.from_buffer(file.read(), mime=True) but it didn't work. This happened with the empty file or the file under 20 KB

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem as well. It's very likely not to do with the file size, because I have tested magic.from_buffer on 90 byte text/plain files as well and it returned the right value.
The problem is that the file has somehow become empty. In my case, this is because the file was a stream and I had already read from the stream (remember if you read from a stream and read again, the second read will start where the first read finished -- unlike reading from the start of a file each time).
This example is from flask

```
mime_type1 = magic.from_buffer(request.stream.read(2048), mime=True) // returns text/plain
mime_type = magic.from_buffer(request.files["file"].stream.read(2048), mime=True) // returns application/x-empty because the stream has already been read from
```

It's hard to exactly diagnose without seeing your earlier code but check where else you are working with the file and comment those out.
You might need to do something like

```
file.seek(0)
mime_type = magic.from_buffer(file.read(), mime=True)
```

Comment: Thank you Alice, I tried your code but it doesn't work. You are right, this happened with the empty file or the file under 20 KB, Especially, the doc file. I have figured out that this is not an issue of Magic library. Sometimes the doc file may return the wrong mime-type, you can use JavaScript or another library to display the mime-type and you will get the same result